# Display comments inside a loop of custom post type in page

Tags: php, wordpress-theming, wordpress

I am trying to add a comments form and list using `comments_template()` to a loop of custom post type.
This loop is displayed inside a page.

The idea is to have a *tips* page with a list of tips (each tip should be a new post so for that I created a custom post type *tips*)

Inside each tip should be a list of comments with a comment form. this comments form is general and applies to multiple post types (they behave regularly).

I looked inside the `comments_template()` function and found this condition that prevents the usage of the function properly:

```
if ( !(is_single() || is_page() || $withcomments) || empty($post) )
    return;
```

This is not the code I use, but this is the idea:

```
// page.php
get_header();

while ( have_posts() ) {
    the_post();

    /**
     * The arguments are created based on the data stored in the settings for this page
     */
    query_posts($args);

    if(have_posts()) {
        while ( have_posts() ) {
            the_post();
            comments_template(); // This won't work
        }
    }
}

get_footer();
```

Here are the settings for the post type:

```
array(
        $labels,
        'publicly_queryable'    => true,
        'has_archive'           => false,
        'menu_position'         => 30,
        'menu_icon'             => 'dashicons-lightbulb',
        'supports'              => array('title', 'author', 'editor', 'revisions', 'comments')
)
```

ideas on how to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

http://danielpowney.com/docs/wp-comments-integration/

Check 'Post Type Support' near the bottom first then the other solutions if comments are already supported for your CPT

Comment: Sorry but, I already added support for comments. I updated the question with the settings I am using.